# How to add text into my game

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement a main menu into my purely javascript/html5 game and I was wondering if it was possible to display text in the game itself! I tried: 
fill(255, 0, 0);
text("Hello!", 50, 50);
but for some reason nothing happens. Is there any way to accomplish this and if not is there any way to make a main menu in pure javascript? Thanks!

Comment: I assume you're using a `<canvas>` tag? Can you share some demo code with us via JSFiddle of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Hmmmmm..... Well the code I am using was based on this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/build-your-first-game-with-html5    . I am trying to make a main menu but I need to implement text into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try using `fillText()`. Here is a tutorial: [HTML5: Drawing images and adding text to the canvas element](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/webmaster/html5-drawing-images-and-adding-text-to-the-canvas-element/586).

Comment: I have read the tut but I am still a bit confused on the implementation of the code into my project...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're referring to the `canvas` element, then you should [refer to here](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-canvas-text.php).  Personally however, I don't see why you couldn't just place an unordered list on top of the canvas and tell the links to trigger events rather than load pages.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#play">Play</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#options">Options</a></li>
    <li><a href="#quit">Quit</a></li>
</ul>
```